# Why is my simple `main` program's ELF header say it's a `DYN (Shared object file)` instead of an executable?

Tags: c++, g++, elf, readelf

Here's a *very* simple C++ program:

```
// main.cpp
int main() {}
```

My `Makefile` generates the following command to compile the program.

```
❯ make
g++ -O0 -fverbose-asm  -o main main.cpp
```

I check with the command `file` to see it's an ELF executable:

```
❯ file main
main: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=921d352e49a0e4262aece7e72418290189520782, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

Everything seems fine **until I try to inspect the ELF header**:

```
❯ readelf -e main
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
...
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
```

From wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header), it appears that there are different types of files such as `EXEC`. Why does it say my simple main program is a shared object and not an executable on the ELF header?

From the limited scope of knowledge I have on `.so`'s, I thought they were libraries that is linked but not loaded until runtime. How does that make sense in this context?

### Extra information:

```
❯ g++ --version
g++ (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

❯ readelf --version
GNU readelf (GNU Binutils) 2.34
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

❯ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    1.4
Distributor ID: Arch
Description:    Arch Linux
Release:    rolling
Codename:   n/a
```

Comment: I get `Type    EXEC (Executable file)` with g++ 9.3.1 and readelf 2.32-31.fc31

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Executables that are as compiled as "position independent executables" (with `-pie`/`-fPIE`) should be relocated to a random address at runtime. To achieve this, they use the DYN type.

Your version of g++ was configured with `--enable-default-pie`, so it sets `-pie` and `-fPIE` by default. You can disable this, and generate a normal executable, by linking with `-no-pie`.

Comment: Thank you! I just checked: `Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure ... --enable-default-pie ...`. You were right. Still strange in my opinion that all executables are by default DYN type. Wouldn't there be some performance penalties by enabling pie always?

Comment: @OneRaynyDay Yes, there is some performance impact. However, most applications spend quite a bit of their runtime in shared libraries anyway which are already position independent. There are security benefits to randomizing the load address of the main program, so many distros take the small perf impact and just build everything position independent.

Comment: The perf impact is actually quite negligible for modern architectures (x86-64), while the security impact of ASLR for binaries has much more value, which is why most distros moved in that direction.